# Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS - MySQL error - unconfigured/dependency errors

Tags: mysql

I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to Ubuntu. I was trying to install a program and update a few more on my system (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS) but I keep on getting a MySQL Error. I'm a bit at a loss as to what all this means:

```
update-alternatives: using /var/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic-utf8 to provide /var/lib/me
cab/dic/debian (mecab-dictionary) in auto mode
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my
.cnf) in auto mode
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
mysqld will log errors to /var/log/mysql/error.log
2020-12-05T10:59:07.377235Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010946] [Server] Failed to start mysql
d daemon. Check mysqld error log.
Warning: Unable to start the server.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysql.service → /lib
/systemd/system/mysql.service.
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: 
enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-12-05 
10:59:10 GMT; 10ms ago
    Process: 67472 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=e
xited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 67480 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 67480 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Data Dictionary upgrade from MySQL 5.7 in progress"
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned
 error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up er
ror from a previous failure.
                            Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.3) .
..
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've now updated that information in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message seems like a good place to start:

```
Status: "Data Dictionary upgrade from MySQL 5.7 in progress"
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned
 error exit status 1
```

If you have recently upgraded from MySQL 5.7 to 8.0, there are a bunch of updates that need to take place with the system databases. The upgrade script is failing for some reason.

The *easiest* solution — so long as you have backups of your important databases or do not need them at all — would be to remove MySQL completely, then re-install. A lot has changed between 5.7 and 8.0, so a fresh installation would likely resolve this for you.

To completely remove MySQL, follow these steps:

1. `sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*`
2. `sudo apt-get purge mysql*`
3. `sudo apt-get autoremove`
4. `sudo apt-get autoclean`
5. `sudo apt-get remove dbconfig-mysql`

It would probably also be a good idea to ensure the data directory is gone.

1. check if `/var/lib/mysql` exists, if so, do (2)
2. `sudo rm -Rf /var/lib/mysql`

From there you can re-install MySQL:

1. `sudo apt install mysql-server`
2. `sudo mysql_secure_installation`
3. (optional) restore databases & user accounts

Hope this helps

Comment: Seems to have worked! Thanks!